# Is it idiomatic to say "more complete"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A meta post [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/714660) gives a list of reputation levels.

I left a comment on that post

> Is it more complete if put reputation of 1 in there?

There are 34 reputation levels in total in that list, no including reputation of 1.

I suppose that list is a complete list of reputation levels up to date.

Based on that, a list including reputation of 1 would have 35 reputation levels.

35 is larger than 34, a list of 35 is **more complete** than the list of 34. Adding more info (reputation of 1) to the complete list, makes it **more complete**, is it idiomatic?

Comment: See also: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11907

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - "complete" means *to the greatest extent or degree; total*. You cannot have gradations of completeness, so something is either complete or it is not. Saying "more complete" would be like saying "more full".

If your list is complete, say it is. The other list is *incomplete*, or is *a partial list*.

Alternatively, you might want to say the 'complete' list is *more comprehensive*, or *the most comprehensive*, which means "including or dealing with *all or nearly all* elements or aspects of something."