# Rightest or the most right

Tags: adjectives

In a dictionary I was trying to find the superlative of 'right' but I couldn't; but I notice that using 'rightest' makes sense, isn't it? Or should we write 'the most' such as It is the rightest  thing or It is the most right thing? Honestly, I have never used 'the most right' nor does it sound good to me.

Comment: *Right* in the sense of correct or the direction?

Comment: Interestingly enough, [rightest](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rightest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crightest%3B%2Cc0) used to be much more common, but it sounds a little strange to modern ears.

Answer (score 2):

[Rightmost](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rightmost) can be used to indicate that which is furthest to the right, but not to indicate that which is most correct.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives can be either [gradable](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/adjectives-gradable-non-gradable) (like hot) or non-gradable (like married).

**Right** and **dead** are both non-gradable. There is no such thing as deader or deadest: likewise, there is no such thing as righter or rightest. You may occasionally hear people using these terms, but they are generally doing so for hyperbolic of humorous effect.

You can, however, be nearly right or nearly dead: maybe that would be a better approach when comparing the relative rightness of things. **partially** can also be used with **right**.

In the UK, it is also common to say **[too right](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/too-right)**, when you agree completely with somebody.

Comment: I don't want to unnecessarily muddy things up, but there are some situations where we can treat a non-gradable adjective as gradable (*very* married for example). The [Difference between “illegal” and “very illegal”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84155/) question has more detail on that.