# Does "quantitative" have a comparative and a superlative?

Tags: adjectives, superlatives, comparative

> While academic fields can create their own algorithms for
>   field-specific problems, they are all joined together by the same
>   basic concepts about finding the best and **most quantitative** ways to
>   tie causes to effects.

Just as "most perfect" or "most square" are nonsensical, does "most quantitative" make any sense?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97696/discussion-on-question-by-zeeshan-ali-does-quantitative-have-a-comparative-and).

Comment: This might also be interesting to folks interested in this question: [Difference between “illegal” and “very illegal”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84155/9161)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether this source is using the strict dictionary definition of "quantitative", or some field-specific usage with a nuanced meaning

> **[quantitative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/quantitative)** (adj): relating to an amount that can be measured

This is a binary, yes/no condition.  Something either *is quantitative* or *is not quantitative*, with no need for comparative or superlative.

*However*, it may be that there is a kind of spectrum between quantitative and qualitative algorithms, and it is possible to define an algorithm that leans more towards the quantitative side of things -- ergo, one that is "more quantitative" than other algorithms.

It's the same with "perfect" and "square".  Yes, as a mathematical concept, something either *is square* or *is not square* -- but in the real world, where nothing is actually square, it's fine to say some shape is "more square" than others.